# Certificate error while running boot2Docker

Tags: terminal, docker

I am using boot2docker which creates a VM of linux on OSX and allows you to use regular docker.

I am following [this](http://ryankennedy.io/running-the-deep=dream)tutorial to try and use google's recent "deep dreams" image software.  There is a python implementation on github that was released and become very popular.  Not knowing python or the frameworks it comes with I decided to look for a simpler way to run it.  So this guy made a container in docker to run it and explains how to set it up in that link.  Unfortunately I am running into a bug where it denies the IP certificate.  AS you can see..

[image: terminal/boot2docker problem]

As recommended by Sabin, this is what i get when i run the curl command.

[image: terminal]

Comment: Are you behind any proxy or VPN? Can you try `curl -v https://index.docker.io:443` and paste the result in your question? Also show what it says if you do `docker login` and put your credentials?

Comment: i posted the curl results however i'm not sure what i need to put in as credentials.

Comment: I think you are missing `boot2docker start && $(boot2docker shellinit)` before doing the `docker run .. ` command. Also you need to replace `/path/to/this/repository` with `\`pwd\`` maybe

Comment: Did it work with the solution?